how can i write a code that accepts an input of a number in digits and gives the output in words
I want to write a code that accepts an input of a number in digits and gives the output in words
example, if I input 7, the output should be seven.
I am new to python.
I tried it literally, but my instructor said that's not a code. please I need community help
